# What is this an example of: "I couldn't fail not to disagree with you less"?

Tags: phrases, figures-of-speech

Eisenhower used it constantly to fend off reporters. Is there a term to describe this type of phrase?

Comment: Awesome, a quadruple negative.

Comment: I always heard that as "I couldn't fail NOT to disagree with you less."  - One of my favorites! "I may be wrong, but I'm not far from it."

Comment: @Orbling Quadruple negative? You mean you have photographs? :P

Comment: @Isaac Truett: If these are Eisenhower's photos, I hope not!

Comment: Similar: *"That young girl is one of the least benightedly unintelligent organic life forms it has been my profound lack of pleasure not to be able to avoid meeting."* Douglas Adams writing the character of Marvin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's a rather extreme case of litotes. From the *New Oxford American Dictionary*:

> ironical understatement in which an affirmative is expressed by the negative of its contrary (e.g., *you won't be sorry*, meaning *you'll be glad*).