# Usage and example of the word “litotes”

Tags: word-usage, rhetoric, litotes

I've come across the word *litotes*, which means a rhetorical understatement. However, I’m having trouble understanding how to use it in colloquial English. Could someone please give an example?

Comment: The best advice on how to use the word _litotes_ in colloquial English is ***don’t***. It’s a very formal, technical word, and people will look at you very strange if you use it in colloquial conversations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ward Farnsworth gives this definition:

> **Litotes** (lye-tuh-teez) occurs when a speaker avoids making an affirmative claim directly and instead denies its opposite. Often this amounts to a double negative.

He gives a whole host of examples in his book *Classical English Rhetoric*. Here is one using the double negative:

> Thus I consent, sir, to this Constitution, because I expect no better, and because I am not sure that it is not the best — Ben Franklin, *at Federal Ratifying Convention* (1787)

However, *litotes* does not have to involve a double negative. It may often simply refer to faint praise, "the most the speaker can offer":

> She was not quite what you would call refined. She was not what you would call unrefined. She was the kind of person that keeps a parrot. — Mark Twain, *Following the Equator* (1897)

It is often used simply as understatement, "a useful tool for indicating small amounts, for making a show of modesty, or for creating a tone of allowance."

> "You'll be quite safe now," the curate was saying in the adjoining room, not without a touch of complacent self-approval such as becomes the victor in a battle of wits. — P. G. Wodehouse, *A Damsel in Distress* (1919)

Let's take something more recent now, from a car campaign by General Motors trying to revive a failing brand by using litotes in an ad slogan to suggest a heroic understatement:

> This is not your father's Oldsmobile.

Meaning? What you thought was a stodgy brand is now thoroughly revamped and revived, enough so that young people will find it exciting. The "not your father's X" (or grandfather's X, etc.) slogan has become a familiar trope, and is used in many similar constructions nowadays.

**Addendum** It is worth noting that George Orwell [famously had a problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20170209143123/http://chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2013/04/08/orwell-and-the-not-unblack-dog/) with the "not un-" construction. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: *Litotes* is hardly a word I expect to hear come up often in  my own colloquies, nor in those around me. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I wouldn't say that is not unsurprising.

Answer (score 2):

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) has lots of the standard examples.  Statements like "this is a not inconsiderable problem."

Comment: Double Negatives such as the one in your example are what I often see when people are explaining Litotes. When I first learned about it, I seem to remember also being told that it involved use of adverbs like so: Only $5m! Here, by using 'only', we imply that 5m is a small amount. Am I right to call this Litotes?

Comment: @Karl: The double negatives seem to be most common, but my understanding is that examples like yours are also considered litotes.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick search of the site:

- [“I couldn't fail not to disagree with you less”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14869/what-is-this-an-example-of-i-couldnt-fail-not-to-disagree-with-you-less)
- [“not uncommon”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20629/are-not-uncommon-and-similar-phrases-double-negatives-should-their-use-be-avoi)

Answer (score -1):

I could imagine if you say "That was meant as a litotes" to a girl  the girl would understand it as a word for compliment and say "Thanks for the compliment".
Well, I wouldn't use such special terms of rhetorics in a normal conversation.