# What does "not the least of which" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I think **"not the least of which"** means **"one of the biggest"** or **"one of the 
important"**.
Is it right?

Comment: Answered (for litotes in general) at [Usage and example of the word “litotes”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/usage-and-example-of-the-word-litotes)

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, though, like many expressions of relative amount in English, the precise meaning is quite ambiguous and context-dependent.

Comment: No, it means precisely what it says. Furthermore, we prefer questions that do not ask for a yes–no answer, because as phrased these tend to generate low-quality answers, and are seldom of any use to future visitors, only to the asker themself. You can help that by editing your question to include more details and research. After all, if you just need to know whether you are right about something, it does not have to be entered into the Stack Exchange Futurepedia for all time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase can be used to mean "one of the biggest" or "one of the most important." However, this meaning isn't necessarily the meaning implied by the speaker. Taken literally, it means that the object in question or the person to whom one is referring is not the member or object considered to be the least important (or the smallest) in the referenced group.