# Not the least being that of becoming

Tags: meaning

*For the moment, he will also be aware of other odds that are stacked against him **not the least being that of becoming** the first Pakistani PM to complete a full term.*

In the above sentence, why did the writer use the phrasing *not the least being that of becoming*? I do not understand what it means.

Comment: The answer can be found in this thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273284/what-does-not-the-least-of-which-mean

Comment: And in future, as mentioned on [ask], you should include in the question the basic research (using online searches, dictionaries etc.) you have done _before_ asking the question.

Comment: Thank you sir.... I have poor writing skill please suggest me how to improve my writing skill ...

Answer (score -1):

These few words require many more to explain!

1. The first part of the sentence refers to "odds" that are stacked against the person in question;
2. "odds" in this context means factors or considerations or circumstances;
3. "not the least" is shorthand for saying that there are a number of odds, some more important than others; opinions may differ on what is the most important, but the following item, if not the most important, is certainly not the least important - hence "not the least";
4. The second part of the sentence defines this particular factor or circumstance which is not the least - "becoming the first Pakistani PM to complete a full term".

By the way, the words "other odds" in this context suggests that the text which came before this sentence has already discussed one or more odds or factors.

I hope that helps.